# What is wrong with "I laughed so hard that my parents are mad"

Tags: grammaticality

I know that it should be something like "my parents became mad" but I can't quite pinpoint the reason and come up with an eloquent explanation.

Something to do with it needing to be a change in state...? But why?

Comment: Who told you there’s something “wrong”? *Became* isn’t so hot, really. Try *got*.

Comment: @tchrist it just doesn't sound right to me...

Comment: @tchrist -  is that *got mad* or have they *gone mad*?

Comment: I read your sentence as meaning 'I laughed so hard that my parents became mad at me (for laughing so hard)' - which seems like an unlikely scenario. The 'that' in the middle of the sentence makes the meaning unclear. I'm guessing that what you mean is 'I'm laughing a lot *because* my parents are so angry'? Is that what you meant?

Comment: It is difficult to answer because it is not clear what you are intending to say. Do you mean "I laughed so hard because my parents were being silly", or do you mean "I laughed so hard that my parents became angry with me", or something else?

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking The intended meaning was that the laughing caused the parents to become angry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but it sounds a little odd because the two "halves" of the sentence refer to different times. "I laughed" is part tense, but "my parents are mad" is present tense. This sentence implies that the speaker laughed sometime in the past and stopped. It then states that the speaker's parents became mad as a result and that *they're still mad,* which is likely not what the speaker is trying to say. If that is what the speaker is trying to say, a more natural sentence would be something like "I laughed so hard that my parents are still mad." Adding the word "still" clarifies the sentence and adds tone, showing that the speaker believes that their parents are being slightly ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong the way it is. "My parents became mad" is also correct, but has a slightly different meaning:

- "My parents are mad" means that they're still mad.
- "My parents became mad" doesn't have that nuance (they became mad, and maybe they're still mad, but maybe they're not).